# How to export a public inner/nested class when visibility is in effect?

Tags: c++, gcc, export, visibility, inner-classes

I'm tidying up a patch that adds visibility to the [Crypto++ library](http://www.cryptopp.com/). According to the [GCC Visibility](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility) wiki:

> Exception catching of a user defined type in a binary other than the
>   one which threw the exception requires a typeinfo lookup... However,
>   this isn't the full story - it gets harder. Symbol visibility is
>   "default" by default but if the linker encounters just one definition
>   with it hidden - just one - that typeinfo symbol becomes permanently
>   hidden (remember the C++ standard's ODR - one definition rule).

My take away: everything (including base classes) need to be exported or decorated with `__attribute__ ((visibility ("default")))`. So I got a list of exceptions from [Exception Class Reference](http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/class_exception.html), and ...

```
class CRYPTOPP_DLL AlgorithmParametersBase
{
public:
    class ParameterNotUsed : public Exception
    {
    public: 
            ...
        }
}
```

And then:

```
cryptopp$ nm -D libcryptopp.so | c++filt | grep ParametersNotUsed
cryptopp$
```

And *if* I rebuild with `class CRYPTOPP_DLL ParameterNotUsed : public Exception`, then I get the same result:

```
class CRYPTOPP_DLL AlgorithmParametersBase
{
public:
    class CRYPTOPP_DLL ParameterNotUsed : public Exception
    {
    public: 
            ...
        }
}
```

Now, I'm fairly certain the base class is exported:

```
$ nm -D libcryptopp.so | c++filt | grep Exception
00000000004d6980 V typeinfo for CryptoPP::Exception
0000000000230700 V typeinfo name for CryptoPP::Exception
00000000004d6bf0 V vtable for CryptoPP::Exception
```

My questions:

- How do I export the inner or nested class since it seems like its not exported?
- Is `nm -D` the correct tool to use to verify the `typeinfo` information?
- Will I be able to catch a `ParameterNotUsed` exception (I suspect not)?
- Will I be able to catch an `Exception` base class exception (I suspect so)?

---

In case it matters:

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

Comment: Is the problem just that you're grepping for `ParametersNotUsed`, but the class is called `ParameterNotUsed` (no `s`)?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to export inner class like this:

```
class Exception {};

class __declspec(dllexport) AlgorithmParametersBase
{
public:
    class ParameterNotUsed : public Exception
    {
    public:
    };
};

// exporting known type
class __declspec(dllexport) AlgorithmParametersBase::ParameterNotUsed;
```

I didn't test the above call however, but it compiles just fine.

Comment: Thanks @CodeKiddy. Its Linux, not Windows.